# How to redirect roodomain/addondomain urls to addondomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My host does not know how to fix this.
I saw in google results URLs that worry me.
For example, I saw   rootdomain/addondomain.com/url1.html  etc
this happened because google bot was not redirected to addondomain.com/url1.html for example

So I want to redirect all URLs to addondomain.com only

Because this created duplicate content.
My root domain has nothing to do with addon domain...they have a completely different topic....

I already have redirection from   addondomain.rootdomain.com  to addon domain in htaccess....
but I want to add the new one too...

This is the code I already have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon\.root\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon\.root\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.addon\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

here is the example with some random domains...

root domain is :  bonesroot.com
addon domain is : beeraddon.com

and beerroot.com files are in the folder bones.com/beer on the server

so I want to create immediate redirection from bonesroot.com/beer to beeraddon.com
is that possible or will it affect the server?

this video explains what I want to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRm6deeeTVY

and here is the code they recommend

```
RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addonfolder/(.*)$
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: _"this video explains what I want to do"_ - please don't rely on any such external resources, for the basic explanation of your problem, or what you want to achieve. Describe it, inside the question, using your _words_.

Comment: When describing the problem please be consistent in the naming of the domains/directories. You have used several different "example" names referring to the same thing which is confusing. "here is the example with some random domains..." - and half way through you change the names again!?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addonfolder/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
> ```

This is the right idea, but it only triggers a 404. To redirect from `https://root.example/addon.example/foo` to `https://addon.example/foo` you would need to do it like this:

```
# Redirect requests to the subdirectory the addon domain points to
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?root\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(addon\.example)(?:$|/(.*)) https://$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes that the subdirectory `/addon.example` is the same as the name of the addon domain, as described initially in your question. (However, for some reason, you have changed this convention later in your question?! <sup>***1**</sup>)

The `$1` backreference contains the subdirectory name (the same as the name of the addon domain). The `$2` backreference contains the URL-path less the initial slash prefix.

The `RewriteCond` directive that you previously had that checked against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is not required as this check is better performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

---

<sup>***1**</sup> If the name of the subdirectory is different to the name of the addon domain then you will need to hardcode this instead. For example:

```
# Redirect requests to the subdirectory the addon domain points to
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?root\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^addon-directory(?:$|/(.*)) https://addon.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

TIP: Addon domains (cPanel?) don't need to point to subdomains that point to subdirectories off the main domain. They can point anywhere... including areas outside of the main domains document root. This would avoid having to implement these redirects to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

OK I will explain again. I will use fake domains in this case but very similar to my actual domains

The root domain is  alter.org

addon domain is numero.com

numero.com files reside inside  alter.org/numero/   folder

I want to keep my current redirects which are also

numero.alter.org/foo    which redirects to numero.com

what I have in htaccess is this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^numero\.alter\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.numero\.alter\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.numero\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

and I want to add also redirect which redirects

alter.org/numero/foo   to numero.com/foo

because I saw one google search result like that and it is duplicate content...Immediately when google bot hits the alter.org/numero/foo it needs to be redirected to numero.com/foo

Please tell me how to add a new redirect to the existing one